# Calc 2 help, volume formed by solid

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid formed when the region bounded by the surface whose coordinates are $y=\sin x$, $y=\cos x$, $x$ varying from $x=0$ to $x= \pi/4$, is rotated around the $x$-axis.

Please help I’m totally lost on what to do thank you!

Comment: There is a topic in college calculus (also covered in high school calculus) called "volumes of revolution".  So you should include some context for your Question.  Have you seen problems of this kind worked in a calculus course?  What difficulty did you encounter in trying to apply the methods presented there?

Comment: I’m just not sure how to calculate the volume rotating it around the x-axis here since there is a gap between the x-axis and the graph of sinx on that interval

Comment: You should refer to your course materials for a discussion of the *disk* method versus the *shell* method.  These are two ways to go about setting up a definite integral to represent the volume.  I'm sure that your instructor intended this exercise to reinforce learning this material.  At a glance I think the disk method is easier to apply to this solid of revolution, but often it is possible to apply both methods and get equal results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A volume rotated about the x axis using the washer method which conceptually sums the volume of a set of infinite washers from $x = 0$ to $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ each with thickness dx.

The outer radius of the washers is $\cos(x)$

The inner radius of the washers is $\sin(x)$

The thickness of a washer is $\ dx$

The volume of a single washer is therefore $\pi(\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2)\ dx$

The volume of all the washers is: $$\mbox{Volume} =\pi\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}\cos (x)^2-\sin (x)^2\ dx$$

[image]

Comment: @Steph:  If you found this Answer (or another one) helpful, you can show that by accepting the Answer (big green checkmark to the left of the body of the Answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the graph you get when plotting those functions in thah interval:

```
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i0hast2qg6
```

See it like this. You have a ceiling and a floor. The greater function (ceiling) is `cosx` and the lesser (floor) is `senx`. Since you already know that and know that the region rotates around x-axis (perpendicular to a rectangle of width dx), use the "washers method":

$$pi\int_1^{pi/4}(cosx)^2-(sinx)^2dx$$

This method is useful when you know that the rotating axis is perpendicular to dx. Now you can use this for a lot other problems. Just pay attention to wheter that $$floor-ceiling$$ relationship changes along the interval, in which case you need to separate the integral in subintervals. This happens if you integrate the same two functions in the interval https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jas6k435df $$[0,5pi/4]$$